# Let p be a prime. Prove that there are ϕ(p−1) many primitive roots mod p.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm new to number theory and the only proof I've been able to find is the one here http://math453spring2009.wikidot.com/lecture-24

however its a bit over my head, is there a more elementary way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

The lecture notes you linked proved a more general result, and then applied it to give this result as a corollary. Here's a more direct (and hopefully elementary enough to your taste) proof of the fact you quote in your title. My proof assumes that at least one primitive root *does* exist.

---

Say you have a primitive root $a$ mod $p$. Then every power $a^i$ mod $p$, up to and including $a^{p-1}\equiv 1$ is a different number (that is what a primitive root *is*, after all). Let $n$ be some positive integer less than and coprime to $p-1$. Then I claim that $a^n$ is also a primitive root.

To see this, observe that for $1 \leq i \leq p-1$, none of the powers $(a^n)^i = a^{in}$ can be the same mod $p$, since the exponents $in$ are all different mod $p-1$, and $a$ is a primitive root.

Now, if $n$ is less than $p-1$ but *not* coprime to it, there is some $i \lt p-1$ such that $in \equiv 0$ mod $p-1$, and thus $a^{in}\equiv 1$ mod $p$. Then $a^n$ cannot be a primitive root, as $(a^n)^{i+1} \equiv a^n$ mod $p$, and some residues are "left out", by a counting argument.

We can therefore say that if we have a primitive root $a$, the powers of $a$ that are also primitive roots are exactly the ones where the exponent is coprime to $p-1$. There are $\phi(p-1)$ of these. But since every non-zero residue mod $p$ is a power of $a$, we must have counted *all* the primitive roots, and thus the result is clear.